# Python: Dictionary that will pull data from every row

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary that will give me the values for each state that I plug into the key value. Here's my code:

`sat_partic = {'State': 'Participation'}`

but this just gives me the variables i inputted in the curly brackets.

I appreciate your help and suggestions.

```
        State   Participation   
0       Alabama     5%  
1       Alaska     38%  
2       Arizona    30%  
3       Arkansas   20%  
4       California 14%
```

Comment: Is this `pandas`?

Comment: I think you are looking for [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete answer:

```
d = df.set_index('State')['Participation'].to_dict()
```

However, in many situations this is not necessary, since you can use `pd.Series.get` with similar functionality.

For example, you can use:

```
d = df.set_index('State')['Participation']
```

Then use `d.get('Alabama')`, etc, to retrieve Participation.

Comment: Thank you! Have not come across these concepts yet - so thank you for the lesson.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries use key-value pairs. So you could use the states as keys (each state occurs only once, right?) and the percentages as values:

```
sat_partic = {"Alabama": 5, "Alaska": 38, "Arizona": 30, ...}
```

Comment: I like this. Its the long way round but you're right States occurs only once. Besides while I'm still learning - the muscle memory of doing this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if below code solves your purpose. But, here I go. You can use `namedtuple`

```
from collections import namedtuple

columns = 'State Participation'

STAT_PARTIC = namedtuple('stat_partic', columns)

print (STAT_PARTIC._fields)
input_data = ['Alabama 5%', 'Alaska 38%', 'Arizona 30%', 'Arkansas 20%',
              'California 14%']

list_all_data = []

for line in input_data:
    data = line.split()
    stat_part = STAT_PARTIC(*data)
    list_all_data.append(stat_part)

print (list_all_data[0].State)
print (list_all_data[0].Participation)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Could you show the desirable output?** I am not sure if I understood well. But...

Why not using pandas library and changing State names into index?

```
import pandas as pd

ser1 = pd.Series(['5%','38%','30%','20%','14%'],['Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','Arkansas','California'])

ser1[:]
```

Out:

```
Alabama        5%
Alaska        38%
Arizona       30%
Arkansas      20%
California    14%
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is really efficient. Thank you.